# Python: DataFrame ndarray distance with proper function for each column type?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

Having this DataFrame:

**self.data_frame=pd.read_csv(self.path, delimiter=self.delimiter)**

```
   height  weight  shoe_size  age  name
0     175      70         40   30  John
1     175      75         39   41  Frank
2     175      69         40   33  Bill
3     176      71         40   35  George
4     178      81         41   27  John
5     169      73         38   49  Jonathan
6     170      65         39   30  Rick
```

I need to calculate the distance of each row from all the others, cell by cell.

For the numeric columns I'm calculating the diff in the following way:

columns_data: ndarray = self.data_frame["weight","height"].values

```
[[70, 175]
 [75, 175]
 [69, 175]
 [71, 176]
 [81, 178]
 [73, 169]
 [65, 170]]
```

dist: ndarray = np.abs(columns_data[:, None] - columns_data)

and I'm getting such array:

```
[[[ 0,  0],
  [ 5,  0],
  [ 1,  0],
  [ 1,  1],
  [11,  3],
  [ 3,  6],
  [ 5,  5]],

 [[ 5,  0],
  [ 0,  0],
  [ 6,  0],
  [ 4,  1],
  [ 6,  3],
  [ 2,  6],
  [10,  5]],

 [[ 1,  0],
  [ 6,  0],
  [ 0,  0],
  [ 2,  1],
  [12,  3],
  [ 4,  6],
  [ 4,  5]],

 [[ 1,  1],
  [ 4,  1],
  [ 2,  1],
  [ 0,  0],
  [10,  2],
  [ 2,  7],
  [ 6,  6]],

 [[11,  3],
  [ 6, 3],
  [12,  3],
  [10,  2],
  [ 0, 0],
  [ 8,  9],
  [16,  8]],

 [[ 3,  6],
  [ 2,  6],
  [ 4,  6],
  [ 2,  7],
  [ 8,  9],
  [ 0,  0],
  [ 8,  1]],

 [[ 5,  5],
  [10,  5],
  [ 4, 5],
  [ 6,  6],
  [16,  8],
  [ 8,  1],
  [ 0,  0]]
]
```

So my problem comes with the **name** column, which is made of strings.
I would use the Levenshtein distance between words, but how can I specify a function for each column type while generating the ndarray?

Answer (score 1):

if you need to apply a specific function to each column in a Dataframe use the map method. The map method takes in first the function you would like to use, then as many list as there are parameters to the function that you are using. `map(func, iter)`. `map` will return a map object so always cast the map to a list, 
`list(map(func, iter)`
For example if you wanted to subtract all of the values in column height from weight you would do

```
def subtract(a, b):
    return a - b
self.data_frame['height minus weight'] = list(map(subtract, self.data_frame['height'], self.data_frame['weight']))
```

keep in mind that what I am doing is creating an entirely new column in the Dataframe. If you would like to just store it in a numpy array you would change `self.data_frame['height minus weight'] = list(map(subtract,self.data_frame['height'], self.data_frame['weight']))` to `array = np.array(list(map(subtract,self.data_frame['height'], self.data_frame['weight'])))`

Comment: The diff is not between different columns, but instead it's between all rows, on all columns.

E.g.: For row 0 I want to calculate the difference on each column with all the other rows and store the values as an array. Repeat this for each row.